# python selenium clicking on a link with no static url

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I would like to look at a certain page multiple times, and extract data from it.

the page I want to get data from has the option to view records showing 5, 10, 100 at a time.

But when I inspect this page there is no static url, where I can change the  nuumber in the url to change the number of entries shown.

After examining the source using firebug I see this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="lconn.profiles.
Friending.setItemsPerPage(this,100)
" title="Show 100 items per page">100</a>
```

I do not know if selenium has a click method which would let me click this page, given I can't find a static url. It would be even better if I could use selenium to inject this javascript onclick event with my own number, sometimes there are over 100 records to display.

**Does **selenium and python have a function to force a javascript action, or would I have to scrape the page to find out the number of pages, then use send keys to access each page?

Comment: You can execute javascript code in selenium https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs , anyways you can get the <a> tag and once you have the element just do element.click() and selenium will make a click on that button/link

Comment: Selenium does have a `click` method; `element.click()`.